# Netbeans compiles and executes fine; but I can't compile at command line

Tags: java, javac

Netbeans compiles and runs my project fine. But I can't compile from command line, probably because I have ONLY been relying on Netbeans to compile since beginning Java a year ago and have little command line experience. Mea culpa; but I've been wrestling with this all afternoon in between Googling and re-reading. And my text says:

*If all the source files for a program are in the current directory then compiling the file containing a definition of main()compiles all the source files for the program.*

So if that's not correct, what is?

Here's the directory structure:

```
C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src\GridLayout3x3>dir
 Volume in drive C is C:
 Volume Serial Number is C43F-51D2

 Directory of C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src\GridLa
yout3x3

12/09/2013  05:19 PM    <DIR>          .
12/09/2013  05:19 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/11/2014  04:59 PM             1,730 Check.java
06/11/2014  05:01 PM             4,619 GridLayout3x3.java
               2 File(s)          6,349 bytes
```

Here's me trying to compile and the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src\GridLayout3x3>javac
GridLayout3x3.java
GridLayout3x3.java:140: error: cannot find symbol

    if (Check.didWin(who)){
        ^
  symbol:   variable Check

  location: class GridLayout3x3

1 error
```

Here's the significant part of the code:

```
package GridLayout3x3;

...

public class GridLayout3x3 implements ActionListener {

...

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        who = 0;
        new GridLayout3x3();
      }
    });
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int row, col;

    xGoesFirstFrame.setVisible(false);

    if (e.getActionCommand().startsWith("Ref")) {
      guiFrame.dispose();
      who = 0;
      new GridLayout3x3();//      main(null);
    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().startsWith("Con")) {
      winnerFrame.setVisible(false);
      jackFrame.setVisible(false);
      return;
    }
    String r = e.getActionCommand().substring(1, 2);
    String c = e.getActionCommand().substring(2, 3);
    try {
      row = Integer.parseInt(r);      col = Integer.parseInt(c);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
      return;
    }
    if (!button[row - 1][col - 1].getText().isEmpty())
      return;
    button[row - 1][col - 1].setText(player.substring(who, who + 1));



    if (Check.didWin(who)){ // error right here ********************



      declareWinner(who);
      who = 1;
    }
    who = 1 - who;
  }
} // end class



package GridLayout3x3;

import static GridLayout3x3.GridLayout3x3.*;

public class Check {
...



  public static boolean didWin(int w) { // calling this *********************



    boolean maybe;
    maybe = checkRows(w) || checkCols(w) || checkDiags(w);
    if (maybe) {
      return true;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        if (button[r][c].getText().isEmpty()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    jackFrame.setVisible(true);
    return false;
  }  
}
```

What the heck did I do wrong?????

I'll gladly submit entire program but surely there's something obvious.

Comment: Try going up a folder (or two) in the command line. The package plays a part in where the compiler looks, so if you're inside the package, the compiler obviously won't find the package inside itself.

Comment: Yep, go into the src directory. Compile `javac -cp . GridLayout3x3.GridLayout3x3.java`. Don't forget `-cp .`

Comment: Note that for future reference, I believe that package names should begin with lower-case letters.

Comment: Try compiling both java files javax Check.java GridLayout3x3.java

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels--I renamed package, but here's what it took to compile: From the `src` directory:
`C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src>`

I had to use (?) the fully-qualified name:`javac -cp . C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src\gridLayout3x3\GridLayout3x3.java`

Here is how DOS saw `classpath` until I changed it:
`classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`. Now it's   `classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects` but still need full pathname.

I feel like a moron...

Comment: I don't expect to be tutored on how to use `javac`.... In fact, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144012/how-to-compile-run-the-java-code-via-javac-java) is a similar thread:

Comment: Here's an amusing note... NOW with classpath as shown in my previous long comment, in this folder `C:\Users\Dov\Documents\!Docs\NetBeansProjects\Tictactoe\src>` this command DOES compile: `javac -cp . gridLayout3x3\GridLayout3x3.java`